# App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I've created an ms teams app, that works fine if i launch it locally, however when i install the appackage in my team and launch the app, it shows me the following error in the console:

App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match.

my app in azure AD has been configured for multitenancy, with a unique id. And i've added webApplicationInfo object in the manifest file:
",
"webApplicationInfo": {
"id": "bae.....a8",
"resource": "https://xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/ba.....a8"
}"

i tried changing the resource object form https from the manifest and azure to api://, it didnt work, i've also added the query "inTeamsSSO=true" to my static tab. Static tab scopes are: "Team"

how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Could you please share your manifest file so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: hi @ChetanSharma-msft, here's the link to my manifest file: 
https://mega.nz/file/0EI0VB7Q#rtKka_0UCEzq3UVWu1EV2PgMi6XLDlK5KY2-y_X9HuE

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft any update regarding this?

Comment: I am checking it from my end and let you know in sometime.

Answer (score 3):

Please verify the contents of webApplicationInfo section:

```
"webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "{AAD App client id}",
    "resource": "api://{Your tab app domain}/{AAD App client id}"
  }
```

Please make sure the domain in webApplicationInfo is same as your tab app's domain, otherwise Teams will return error.

Comment: And that the app registration Application ID URI is the same

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT what do you mean by tab app domain? Where is it defined?
Also, how can it be solved in local debug and in prod?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, a project I'm working on uses a federation server url as the Azure app's resource url (of the form https://federation-sts.companyname.com/auth/realms/appname) but the static tabs content urls are located elsewhere. Could you offer me some hints on how to make it work?

Comment: Are you getting the same error? `App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match.`